# Echo arrays in html code

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have arrays like that

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
[mounts] => Array
                (
                    [collected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Chauffeured Mekgineer's Chopper
                                    [itemId] => 120968
                                    [qualityId] => 7
                                    [icon] => inv_misc_key_06
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Albino Drake
                                    [itemId] => 44178
                                    [qualityId] => 4
                                    [icon] => ability_mount_drake_blue
                            )
```

I need the [itemId] of every array (they are numerated [0]-[xy] in this code:

```
<img src="http://media.blizzard.com/wow/renders/npcs/rotate/test.jpg" width="268" height="226"
        class="reel"
        data-image="http://media.blizzard.com/wow/renders/npcs/rotate/[ITEMID].jpg"
        data-frames="24"
        data-frames="1"
        data-footage="24"
        data-revolution="800">
```

**The code is for a jquery 360° view-script of an picture. So i´m not sure if this is compatible with php.**

My try:

```
foreach ($r['result']['mounts']['collected'] as $item) echo '
            <li>
                <a 
                    href="//de.wowhead.com/item=', $item['itemId'], '"
                    class="', $item['qualityId'], '"
                >
                    <img
    src="http://media.blizzard.com/wow/renders/npcs/rotate/test.jpg" class="reel"
        data-image="http://media.blizzard.com/wow/renders/npcs/rotate/', $item['itemId'], '.jpg"
        data-frames="24"
        data-frames="1"
        data-footage="24"
        data-revolution="800""
                        alt="', htmlspecialchars($item['name']), '"
                    >
                </a>
            </li>';
```

Comment: What is wrong with your try?

Comment: You should be using a period (`.`) for concatenation, not a comma (`,`).

Comment: The 360° view-script doesn´t appear. My question is now, is it possible to execute a jquery script in a php script?

Comment: @PatrickQ: `echo()` takes multiple params.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, I should have clarified.  I meant more in terms of convention.  Hence why I didn't say "You have to...".